# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar las librerías de acceso a MEGA en Android?

Tags: android, seguridad, google-play, openssl

He desarrollado una aplicación para Android que tiene acceso a la nube MEGA.

La aplicación funciona perfectamente, pero al subirla al Play Store me la bloquean porque dicen los de Google que la versión que uso de OpenSSL tiene un agujero de seguridad, que tengo que actualizarlo.

Mensaje original de google:

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> We rejected Detector de Movimiento, with package name com.sicre.dm,
>   for violating our Malicious Behavior or User Data policy.... OpenSSL
>
> The vulnerabilities were addressed in OpenSSL 1.02f/1.01r. You can
>   find more information and next steps in this Google Help Center
>   article. https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6376725

Mi problema es que tengo las librerías de MEGA de su página oficial y no tienen ninguna actualización, y lo que explica Google para poder actualizarlas no tengo ni idea de cómo se hace.

Google te indica una pagina para solucionar el problema, pero hay que actualizar las librerías de OpenSSL y recompilar el directorio jni (por lo visto) y no tengo ni idea de hacer todo eso. Si hubiera alguien que haya hecho una aplicación con acceso a MEGA podría ayudarme, ya que debería tener las librerías actualizadas.

Comment: Estás seguro que son las librerias de MEGA las que te dan problemas?  has probado a actualizar otras que tengas?

Comment: Seguro que son las librerias de MEGA. He editado la pregunta y he adjuntado el mensaje de google. Gracias.

Comment: Supongo que contactar al soporte de MEGA sería una buena opción.